# Javascript custom logging utility interferes with chrome inspector behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am writing my own logging utility by overriding default console.log as follows

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);
console.log = function() {
    this.logCopy.apply(console, addStampToArgs(arguments));
};
```

I am using chrome's inspector for debugging.

My approach works fine except one issue which is now I am not able to use chrome inspectors feature where it shows `<file>:<line-number>` for each log line with a link to code.

Now it shows every log line originating from my console.log wrapper function.

How can I make my wrapper function to be un-trackable by console so that I get the correct  `<file>:<line-number>`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that console logging facilities work by side-effect and therefore don't lend themselves to composition.

They all return `undefined`:

### Console

```
console.log("me")
me
<- undefined
console.warn("me")
me
<- undefined
console.error("me")
me
<- undefined
console.trace()
console.trace()
(anonymous function)
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluate
<- undefined
```

I would also be interested in Javascript custom logging, to get access to the nifty printf-like formatting features, e.g. %o, %O, %d, %s, %c, ...

### Console

```
console.log("%o", [[{}, 1, "two"]]);
[Array[3]]
0: Array[3]
0: Object
1: 1
2: "two"
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
<- undefined
```

They can also handle circular references, which is hard to achieve with `JSON.stringify`.

I am playing with this in Google Chrome (canary) Source Snippets.

There I noticed it logging stack trace information via a new snippet scheme, but the link just opens an empty tab with no access to devtools there.

### Snippet

```
try {
    console.trace();
    console.log("hi");
    FIXME
} catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception.stack);
}
```

### Console

```
console.trace() consolation.js:2
(anonymous function) consolation.js:2
hi consolation.js:3
ReferenceError: FIXME is not defined
    at snippets:///14_224:4:5 consolation.js:6
undefined
```

But, alas, as for your question, answers I have none.

Writing this as a comment would not have rendered well.